Neovim syntax highlighting from STDIN
I am trying to get Neovim to auto-detect the filetype/syntax when piping text into nvim.
Example:
docker inspect 1234 | nvim

Outputs JSON as follows:
[
    {
        "Id": "0e4e1f41537f65db87c8cd5759f6880d102fd3f067c8d750ce5112f313aecefc",
        "Created": "2024-09-04T05:09:59.171739085Z",
        "Path": "python3",
        "Args": [
            "manage.py",
            "runserver",
            "0.0.0.0:8000"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 57059,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2024-09-04T05:10:16.203564593Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]


This outputs a JSON string, but Neovim cannot detect the language from the text, but without a filetype, it has no syntax highlighting.
I know that I could create an alias such as vimjson that runs nvim -c 'set filetype=json' but I am looking for something simpler that works for any language server I have installed.

Could you give is an example of the output of docker inspect 1234? If it is a json file Neovim could/should detect it based on the content. With an example we could propose you ways to improve the detection.

You can always :setf[iletype] json once Vim has started

Do you still have something open in your question ? How can we help you further ? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

@D.BenKnoble yes, but not setting filetype every time I open vim is what I am trying to accomplish.

@VivianDeSmedt I provided an example of the output. I was hoping that there was some straightforward way for it to say... infer the language similar to how an editor like VS Code will... where you paste any language in and it auto-detects the syntax... but it seems like Neovim works off the file extension.

I would do the following.
I would add a json.vim file into your ~/.config/nvim/ftdetect folder with the following content:
autocmd BufEnter,BufRead *
  \ if matchstr(getline(1) . getline(2) . getline(3), '\v^(\s*(\[|\{))+\s*"[^"]*"\s*:') != '' |
  \   setf json |
  \ endif

The script will make Neovim look at the first three lines of the content of the file and verify that it starts with something like [ { "key" :  or { "key" : before setting the filetype to json.

Perhaps the OP is asking for a solution that is on a temporary basis (like some CLI-based vim option fed into the vim editor)

I wasn't able to get this working. I changed it to match the pattern of the docker output which is a JSON & put it in my init.lua using vim.cmd and it didn't work. I think this is the right direction though... just going to mess around a bit more

Thanks for the example! I have reworked the regular expression and it should work now.

Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Thanks for the feedback :-)
